# Regular Expression for dd-MMM-yy

Tags: forms, validation

I want to enter date in `dd-MMM-yy` format only.

My regular expression is below:

```
$.validator.addMethod("date2",
    function (date1, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || date1.match(/^\(?(\d{2})\)?[- ]?\(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\?[- ]?(\d{2})$/);
}, "Please specify Year in Format DD-MMM-YY Only");
```

But the above regular expression is accepting if I give date in the format `27-May14` also. The '-' in the last is not checking. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `?` after `[- ]?`. The question mark makes it optional.

Answer (score 1):

In dd-MMM-yy (month is case sensetive),
so test these regular expression

^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I see that your Regular support 00-May14

Excample fix:

^([0][1-9]|[12]?\d|3[01])[- ]?(jan|feb|ma[ry]|apr|ju[nl]|aug|sept?|oct|nov|dec)[- ]?(\d{2})$