# Regular expression needed for date/time validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need a JavaScript regular expression for the following date/time format:

10 Jul 2010 15:00

(2 digits space 3 characters space 4 digits space 2 digits colon 2 digits)

Character case does not matter, and the only allowed input is a-z, 0-9, space, colon

Thanks in advance.

For now I don't really understand regular expression in JavaScript but I need this solution

Comment: various duplicates: [Regular Expression for dd-MMM-yy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987446/regular-expression-for-dd-mmm-yy), [Regex for validating date in dd-Mmm-yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463243/regex-for-validating-date-in-dd-mmm-yyyy-format)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for validating date in dd-Mmm-yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463243/regex-for-validating-date-in-dd-mmm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 0):

### Dates are irregular:

For example, the regular expression to ensure you don't get February 29, or February 30 (unless the year is a multiple of 4 and not a multiple of 100 unless it's also a multiple of 400) is not that simple and may not be feasible with regex.

So, this is for just using a very simple regex to check the formatting and nothing else (which I can't suggest really!):

```
\d{2} \([a-z]){3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

/[0-9][0-9] [A-z][A-z][A-z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/

This is only for the specifications you gave (2 digits space 3 characters space 4 digits space 2 digits colon 2 digits) not for date validation